# MySQL Backup File - already has CREATE DATABASE statements

Tags: mysql, database

The MySQL backup file I created was dumped using --all-databases and the "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" statements are in it.

I now have a completely new instance of MySQL that I want to import that dump back into (with no databases in it at all).

What's the correct way to reload this file without specifying a database or is that not even possible. Do I have to create all or just one of the databases first to be able to execute the command properly ?

All the examples I can find specify "mysql -u xxx [database] < [backupfile]" or "USE database" first but what's the point of having a dump that has the "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS" statements if you have to create the database(s) on your own to import it anyways... ?

Answer (score 1):

Please note the [`IF NOT EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-database.html) clause. The backup file is prepared to handle both situations: when the database already exists (you have created it manually or maybe you dropped all the tables from the existing database and want to restore it from the backup) and when you want to import the backup into a new server where the database doesn't exist yet.

You can simply run `mysql -h {host} -u {user} -p < {backupfile}` on a command line terminal and your database is up and running again.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the tip. I ended up using "mysql -u root -p -e 'source ...' " because powershell reserves the "<" character. Furthermore, powershell saved the dump in UTF-16 and made even more headaches by causing a --binary-mode error on importing but I got it back up and going finally. I didn't have to specify or use a database first by using the "-e 'source path' " switch and that was my real question here. Thanks.